# Imprimir destacado valores específicos da matriz

Tags: php, array-multidimensional

Em meus estudos aqui com matrizes estou tentando destacar apenas os valores impares (deixar em negrito), mas não estou entendo como fazer isso. Abaixo segue o que fiz, mas estra imprimindo tanto os números em negrito como os normais.

```
 <?php
 $matriz = array(
     array(50, 35, 44),
     array(25, 11, 32),
     array(53, 95, 78)
 );
 foreach ($matriz as $v1) {
     foreach ($v1 as $v2) {
         echo $v2, ' '; // imprime todos valores com espaço
         if ($v2 & 1) { // se for impar
             echo '<b>', $v2, '</b>';
         }
     }
     echo '<br/>';
 }
 ?>
```

Comment: de onde veio esse ``$v2 & 1`` ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/600202/understanding-php-ampersand-bitwise-and-operator

Comment: Porque editaram meu código? Ele estava muito bem visualizado.

Comment: phpricardo, acho que só o `array` se visualiza melhor como @RodrigoRigotti fez, mas realmente é uma questão de gosto e opinião. Rodrigo, a gente só devia identar quando é um amador postando código *spaguetti*. Se fosse meu post, eu revertia as chaves pra uma nova linha, pois é o estilo que prefiro.

Comment: @brasofilo entendi. na verdade eu costumo corrigir o código conforme os padrões que a galera do PHP-FIG está definindo, é só uma teimosia minha :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seu problema foi um simples erro de lógica ao utilizar dois `echo` para imprimir os itens, o correto seria o seguinte:

```
    foreach ($matriz as $v1){
       foreach ($v1 as $v2){
          // eu removi o echo daqui
           if ($v2 & 1) { // se for impar
               echo '<b>', $v2, ' </b>';
           } else {
              echo $v2,' '; // e coloquei ele aqui
           }
       }
       echo '<br/>';
   }
```

O que estava errado era que você primeiro imprimia todos os itens do array, e depois criava um `if()` imprimindo **uma segunda vez** os itens que eram ímpares, desta vêz em negrito. Por isto estes itens ficavam duplicados.

Comment: Perfeito Kazzkiq, realmente estava fazendo errado, ainda tenho problemas com lógica infelizmente. Obrigado pela resposta.

Answer (score 2):

Para saber se um número é para ou impar, use o seguinte:

Par:

```
$numero % 2 == 0
```

Impar:

```
$numero % 2 == 1
```

Assim fica mais claro o que quer dizer, na minha opinião.

Além disso, não usaria `<b>` e sim `<strong>`.

Comment: Dessa maneira da para fazer o teste também Miguel. ;)

Comment: Dica do strong acatada. :D